# Get eclipse (java) to work with java3d

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I have a simple java project (adapted from the example [here](http://goblinbashing.blogspot.de/2010/05/setting-up-java3d-with-eclipse.html)), which is as follows:

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld()
    {
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("PATH : " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        new HelloWorld();        
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Hello World!
PATH : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no j3dcore-ogl in java.library.path
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
  at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline$1.run(NativePipeline.java:231)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibrary(NativePipeline.java:200)
  at javax.media.j3d.NativePipeline.loadLibraries(NativePipeline.java:157)
  at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:987)
  at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:299)
  at HelloWorld.<init>(HelloWorld.java:10)
  at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:20)
```

I assume this Exception indicates that the library `libj3dcore-ogl.so` could not be found. Here's where it is located:

```
$ locate libj3dcore-ogl.so
/usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so
```

As the output above shows, `/usr/lib/jni` is inside `java.library.path`. What am I doing wrong? (I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and Eclipse 3.7.2 - if that may be an issue?)

Java is a bit of unknown territory for me. So please be as verbose as possible on your notes/suggestions/answers.

**Update 1**

Apparantly it's a 64-bit library (on a 64-bit operating system):

```
$ file /usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so
/usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

I use openjdk as runtime environment. Both java3d (`libjava3d-java`) and the openjdk (`openjdk-6-jdk`) is installed via `aptitude`.

Comment: Perhaps the library is the wrong architecture -- 64-bit when you have a 32-bit system, or vice-versa? What does "`file /usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so`" say?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - both are installed via aptitude. It's a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, it works if I compile and run the application from my terminal:

```
javac -classpath /usr/share/java/j3dcore.jar:/usr/share/java/j3dutils.jar:/usr/share/java/vecmath-1.5.2.jar:. HelloWorld.java
java -classpath /usr/share/java/j3dcore.jar:/usr/share/java/j3dutils.jar:/usr/share/java/vecmath-1.5.2.jar:. HelloWorld
```

But I would really like to use eclipse to do this kind of things.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

---

It also works with Eclipse, if I copy the native library (`libj3dcore-ogl.so`) to the jvm directory and add the libraries (`j3dcore.jar`, `j3dutils.jar`, `vecmath-1.5.2.jar`) as external jars to the build path libraries (right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...):

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/
```

But I wonder if there really is no solution that wouldn't require this copy.

Comment: I'm using java1.8 - it no longer requires the copy of ogl to run but it still requires the 3 jars in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I went through similar issues while trying to run a foreign project requiring `java3d`. I'm using Eclipse only for the compilation and packaging runnable jar parts (as it is a Maven project), but the runtime errors I was getting were of the same kind. And I want to confirm that [moooeeeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025391/moooeeeep)'s answer was pertinent and very helpful. The reason why I'm posting here is mainly because I think this can be useful for other people to give the full steps (independently from Eclipse, since setting up things using Eclipse facilities or Maven dependency ones failed, in both cases). **Everything here is all about setting up correctly the JRE**.

**Note:** *I'm working under OpenJDK-7-amd64 (and Debian - 64 bit system). So feel free to adapt the following steps for `i386` if applicable (just replace "**amd64**" by "**i386**").*

***Here's what worked for me then :***

```
sudo apt-get install libjava3d-jni libjava3d-java libvecmath-java
```

This will add required files to be injected in the JRE:

```
$ locate j3d
/usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so
/usr/share/java/j3dcore-1.5.2+dfsg.jar
/usr/share/java/j3dcore.jar
/usr/share/java/j3dutils-1.5.2+dfsg.jar
/usr/share/java/j3dutils.jar
```

Since those files are located in different places but definitely not in the JRE's ones, copy (or link) as follows:

***Dynamic libraries :***

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libj3dcore-ogl.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/
```

***JARs :***

```
sudo cp /usr/share/java/j3d*.jar  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/
sudo cp /usr/share/java/vecmath-*.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/
```

***Resulting in :***

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libj3dcore-ogl.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/j3dcore-1.5.2+dfsg.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/j3dcore.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/j3dutils-1.5.2+dfsg.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/j3dutils.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/vecmath-1.5.2.jar
```

Hope this can be of any help...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on anothe project, this solved it for me:

Open the run configuration of your project, select the "Arguments" tab and insert the following into the "VM arguments" box

> -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni

I don't know why you have to give the path here again. It also doesn't work with relative ones, but this way it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help either. According to the output of my program (see OP), the library path already contains that entry anyway (`/usr/lib/jni`).

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown only if the definition of a native method can't be found.

Comment: I'm quite new to java. What would this imply then?

Comment: It means the JVM is unable to find native code, like code written in C or C++. In your case, I would say, the JVM is unable tà find OpenGL drivers. Make sure your graphic card drivers are OpenGL compliant. Addind the parameters proposed by wurfkeks is probably also a good idea.

Comment: I have other applications that use OpenGL, so I don't expect this to be an issue. I have added the entire trace of the exception. Maybe this is but of diagnostic use?

Comment: You can try to follow these steps: http://www.emouseatlas.org/Software/JavaTools/java3dinstall.html

Comment: Setting the environment variables has no effect apparantly :(